# Trying to show Product Name instead of ID for sales query using Adventure Works database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, adventureworks

I am struggling with getting the product name to show instead of the ID. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT TOP 10 ProductID, SUM(LineTotal) AS SumOfSales
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SOD
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
ON SOD.SalesOrderID = SOH.SalesOrderID
WHERE SOH.OrderDate > '12/31/2012' AND SOH.OrderDate < '1/1/2014'
GROUP BY ProductID
--HAVING SUM(LineTotal) >= 2000000
ORDER BY SUM(LineTotal) DESC
```

Comment: Also just showing the product name with the ID would be fine as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the product table because the product name is available only there. Join the product table on primary and foreign keys to get the required column from the table.

```
SELECT TOP 10 sod.ProductID,prd.<add the required column>, SUM(LineTotal) AS SumOfSales
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SOD
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
ON SOD.SalesOrderID = SOH.SalesOrderID
join Production.Product prd on prd.ProductID  = sod.ProductID
WHERE SOH.OrderDate > '12/31/2012' AND SOH.OrderDate < '1/1/2014'
GROUP BY sod.ProductID,prd.<add the required column>
--HAVING SUM(LineTotal) >= 2000000
ORDER BY SUM(LineTotal) DESC
```

Comment: I keep getting a error that says its not found or its erroring out because of a aggregate function

Comment: add the same column in group by too

Comment: cool. upvote and mark it as answer

Comment: Quick question, is this just listing the names? or do I need to do another join to get the name associated with the ProductID?

Comment: In order to get the product related details that are present in production.product table then you need to join.---- in the solution that was shared earlier, the product table is already joined as 3rd table.

Answer (score 2):

You will also have to join to the Production.Product table

Comment: This is where I am stuck can you help me with this?